# Calling destructor to free dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
        ~A() {}
};
int main(){
        A *p = new A();
        p->~A();
        return 0;
}
```

I would like to know if the memory of the object `A` pointed by `p` is freed or we must to call `delete p;`

Comment: You should not call the destructor explicitly.

Comment: No, it just calls the destructor. `delete` both calls the destructor and deallocates the memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory was not freed. The destructor destroys the object but does not free the memory. How could it? You can destroy objects that are dynamically allocated, are on the stack, are globals, and so on. The destructor has no idea what is needed, if anything, to release the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Memory was allocated using operator [new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and will be freed (deallocated) using operator [delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete), not your object's destructor.

We should not confuse the [object lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) with [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

It is not `A'`s [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) role to free the allocated memory and it should not be called explicitly. It is simply a member function that gets called **when** your object gets destroyed. And it will get destroyed after you call the `delete`.

Replace:

```
p->~A();
```

with:

```
delete p;
```

Now your objects gets destroyed and the allocated memory gets deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between calling destructor or any other member function, except one thing - you should not do it, unless you want to separate object allocation from its construction and destruction.